# iOS: Find out number of fraction digits

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have some numbers that comes from server, how to know how many fraction digits in number ?
I mean how to know that 2.43 has 2 numbers after coma, 3.145 - 3 numbers, 2.0003 - 4 numbers.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Doesn't seem like the most difficult problem to solve.  What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean after the period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a number, change it to a string. Remove the decimal point and get the last object and the length.

Example:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.902];

[number.stringValue componentsSeparatedByString: @"."].lastObject.length;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for number = @(12)

Comment: This won't work if the number hasn't any fraction digits. You need to add a check if the returned array has two items and check the length of the second item (NSString) to get the correct number of fraction digits. If there is no second item, this means that there are no fraction digits.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this :

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:3.902];
NSUInteger i = [[number stringValue] rangeOfString:@"."].location;
long numberOfDigits = [[number stringValue] length]-(i+1);
NSLog(@"%ld", numberOfDigits);
```

> 3

Answer (score 0):

1. convert to string.
2. find the decimal point range.
3. subtract string length from the decimal point position and Add one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are retrieving the data from a server in a stream?

If your getting the data as a stream, it should be prepended with the length of the string, that is how you would know how many places to expect.

So on the server, first convert to string, then determine the length, or use another method suggested, then prepend the length of the string, and then send that number first.